# Schedule library TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm trying to make a gmail bot that sends the same message repeatedly in a time period (for example every hour). Here's what I did:

```
import smtplib
import time
import schedule

sender_email = input("enter ur e-mail: ")
rec_email = input("enter receiver e-mail: ")
password = input("enter your password: ")
message = input("enter message\n-")


def thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    print("login successful")
    server.sendmail(sender_email, rec_email, message)
    print("sent")


schedule.every().hour.do(thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message))
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Please include a full traceback of the error message so we can identify exactly what errored.

Comment: that's what i get as an error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\email_sender2.0\sender2.py", line 20, in <module>
    schedule.every().hour.do(thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message))
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 440, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Answer (score 4):

By passing `thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message)` to `schedule.every().hour.do()`, you're passing the *result* of *calling* `thankyou` with those arguments. Since `thankyou` returns nothing, you're doing the equivalent of `schedule.every().hour.do(None)`. You should instead pass a function, like a lambda function, that *calls* `thankyou` with the arguments you want:

```
schedule.every().hour.do(lambda: thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message))
```

Comment: okay it makes sense thanks but now nothing happens after i write a message and hit enter.

Comment: @berke that must be a separate issue then, you have to ask a new question if you can't figure that out on your own. For a troubleshooting step, did you make sure that `thankyou` is running right away, and not, say, waiting an hour before running?

Comment: @berke Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. If you still need help, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: i changed the line as `schedule.every().second.do(lambda: thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message))` and it works normally. like you said it starts working with the end of the first hour. thank you monsieur @RandomDavis!

Answer (score 3):

it's because your passing `schedule.every().hour.do()` the return of `thankyou()`, not the function itself, try:

```py
schedule.every().hour.do(lambda:thankyou(sender_email, rec_email, password, message))
```

Comment: thanks. any tips to get better or is this code crap?